# How to Check if a User has a Subscription with CanCanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, subscriptions, cancancan

I'm building a subscription site with the Koudoku gem and am attempting to block authorization to my Lessons content using Cancancan until a registered user has a subscription, but I'm having issues setting up the ability.rb file.  Using devise as well.  I want to keep the Lessons: show action blocked until a user buys a subscription.  I'm able to lock the lessons down, but can't come up with the language to unlock them for subscribers.

Was thinking this would work, but no dice.

```
@subscription.user_id == current_user.id
```

What code do I need to insert into ability.rb to get this to work?

Here's an excerpt from my lessons_controller.rb

```
class LessonsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_lesson, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_filter :authenticate_user!

def show
 @subscriptions = Subscription.all
 authorize! :read, @lesson
end
```

the subscriptions schema looks like:

```
create_table "subscriptions", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "stripe_id"
t.integer  "plan_id"
t.string   "last_four"
t.integer  "coupon_id"
t.string   "card_type"
t.float    "current_price"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
end
```

The User schema:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
t.string   "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
t.string   "first_name"
t.string   "string"
t.string   "last_name"
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just figured this out in case anyone wants to know. I changed current_user to just user and added the user || = User.new

Here's the ability.rb code:

```
def initialize(user)
 user ||= User.new

 if Subscription.exists?(:user_id => user.id)
    can :read, Lesson 
 else 
    false
 end
end
```